# addUserScript is not working after WKWebView is initialized

Tags: ios, wkwebview

When I change `WKUserContentController` after `WKWebView` instance created. Here is my code.

```
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let userController = WKUserContentController()
userController.addUserScript(WKUserScript(source: "alert('it works')", injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true))

configuration.userContentController = userController // before instantiate WKWebView

webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: configuration)
webView.navigationDelegate = self
webView.uiDelegate = self

view = webView
```

Above code works fine, but below is not

```
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let userController = WKUserContentController()
userController.addUserScript(WKUserScript(source: "alert('it doesn't work')", injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true))

webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: configuration)
webView.navigationDelegate = self
webView.uiDelegate = self

webView.configuration.userContentController = userController // 
// neither configuration.userContentController = userController

view = webView
```

Why this happens?
In fact, it's okay when I write in code, whatever it's bug or something. However, this bothers me when I use this with storyboard. I cannot change `WKUserContentController` after storyboard instantiate `WKWebView`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't replace the user content controller. Just use the one that the web view already has:

```
let script = // whatever
let config = webView.configuration
config.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
```

That works even if the web view came from a storyboard.

Comment: You right! It works! Thank you very much. I don't know much detail, but I think `WKUserContentController` must be read-only, not only `WKWebViewConfiguration`